# How do I configure an UpdateExpression with nested data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway that stores data in a DynamoDB instance.  My table structure looks like this:

```
{
  "TableName": "stuff",
  "Item": {
    "stuffId": {
      "S": "02b4e004-1132-4b87-a855-20e7d1bd1840"
    },
    "clients": {
      "M": {
        "company_inc": {
          "M": {
            "prod": {
              "S": "null"
            },
            "qa": {
              "S": "null"
            },
            "stage": {
              "S": "null"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to configure my Body Mapping Template so that given an HTTP PATCH request I can update `company_inc.prod`.  For example; given this query string:

```
?stuffId=02b4e004-1132-4b87-a855-20e7d1bd1840&client=company_inc&location=prod&locationIsSet=true
```

I would update the record to look like this:

```
{
  "TableName": "stuff",
  "Item": {
    "stuffId": {
      "S": "02b4e004-1132-4b87-a855-20e7d1bd1840"
    },
    "clients": {
      "M": {
        "company_inc": {
          "M": {
            "prod": {
              "S": "true"
            },
            "qa": {
              "S": "null"
            },
            "stage": {
              "S": "null"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What should an "UpdateExpression" look like to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.  You have to use attribute names like `#client` and `#location` as placeholders in the path for `company_inc.prod`.

```
{
    "TableName": "stuff",
    "Key": {
        "alterId": {
            "S": "$input.params('stuffId')"
        }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "set clients.#attrClientName.#attrLocation = :locationIsSet",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames" : {
        "#attrClientName" : "$input.params('client')",
        "#attrLocation" : "$input.params('location')"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":locationIsSet": {"S": "$input.params('location')"}
    }
}
```